# If a member of the center is selected at random, what is the probability that she does neither?

Tags: probability, statistics

At a particular fitness center, 64.1% of the members take at least one class, 18.6% work with a personal trainer, and 9.2% do both.  If a member of the center is selected at random, what is the probability that she does neither?  The answer is 0.265.  How do I solve this?

Comment: I figured it out.  To solve it:  converted percentages to decimals, then:  0.641+0.186-.092=0.735.  1-0.735=0.265

Answer (score 1):

Just to put you on track.

Let $A$ denote the event that the member takes at least one class.

Let $B$ denote the event that the member works with a personal trainer.

Known to you are the probabilities $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$.

To be found is probability:

$$P(A^c\cup B^c)$$

Realize that $A^c\cup B^c=(A\cap B)^c$.